# Android - Custom image as app background

Tags: android, background, themes, background-image

I am attempting to us a png file that I have imported into the drawable-mdpi folder as my background. however, just setting it as the background through main.xml results in the process stopping unexpectedly when I attempt to run my app in the emulator.

Is there any step by step process I need to follow after setting the png file as the background in main.xml (I have also included my values/theme.xml below)

values/theme.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/pioneer_lift</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting this as a window background you don't need to set it as a background for your layout too. (No reason to have the system draw it twice - it will be slower.)

Have you set your custom theme as your Activity's theme in your manifest?

Comment: no, how should i do that? and what should i put for the windowBackground line in the theme.xml?

Comment: Your theme declaration looks ok. In either your activity tag or your application tag if you want this theme to be global to your whole app, set the attribute `android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground"` to use your custom theme.

Comment: ok, so do i need to remove all theme references form main.xml?

Comment: If by "main.xml" you mean your layout file, yes.

Comment: okay. If I am still getting process stopped unexpectedly, what do i need to do?

Comment: Great! For future reference, when troubleshooting Android app crashes on stackoverflow, the answer to, "If I am still getting process stopped unexpectedly, what do i need to do?" is always, "post the exception from adb logcat so we can see it." :)